# Get mean, min, max from the same column when using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "type": [
            "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "pp", "pp", "pp", "pp", "pp", "pp",
        ],
        "label": [
            "[0,50)",
            "[0,50)",
            "[0,50)",
            "[50,100)",
            "[50,100)",
            "[50,100)",
            "[0,50)",
            "[0,50)",
            "[0,50)",
            "[50,100)",
            "[50,100)",
            "[50,100)",
        ],
        "margin": [
            10, 11, 12, 20, 25, 30, 17, 18, 19, 40, 45, 50,
        ],
    }
)
```

| type | label | margin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cc | [0,50) | 10 |
| cc | [0,50) | 11 |
| cc | [0,50) | 12 |
| cc | [50,100) | 20 |
| cc | [50,100) | 25 |
| cc | [50,100) | 30 |
| pp | [0,50) | 17 |
| pp | [0,50) | 18 |
| pp | [0,50) | 19 |
| pp | [50,100) | 40 |
| pp | [50,100) | 45 |
| pp | [50,100) | 50 |

For each type and label I would like to get mean, min, max in it's own column.

How can I get the desired result

| label | cc_mean | cc_min | cc_max | pp_mean | pp_min | pp_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0,50) | 11 | 10 | 12 | 18 | 17 | 19 |
| [50,100) | 25 | 20 | 30 | 45 | 40 | 50 |

Comment: What is already been tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pivot_table()`:

```
out=df.pivot_table('margin','label','type',aggfunc=['min','max','mean'])
out.columns=[f"{y}_{x}" for x,y in out]
out=out.reset_index()
```

OR

use `pd.crosstab()`:

```
out=pd.crosstab(df['label'],df['type'],df['margin'],aggfunc=['min','max','mean'])
out.columns=[f"{y}_{x}" for x,y in out]
out=out.reset_index()
```

OR

use `groupby()`:

```
out=df.groupby(['type','label']).agg(['min','max','mean']).unstack(0).droplevel(0,1)
out.columns=[f"{y}_{x}" for x,y in out]
out=out.reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    label       cc_min  pp_min  cc_max  pp_max  cc_mean     pp_mean
0   [0,50)      10      17      12      19      11          18
1   [50,100)    20      40      30      50      25          45
```

Comment: I would suggest using groupby and agg because it is the most readable and easy to understand option